# Using threading.Timer to run code at regular time intervals in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am using the following approach to run certain code on Raspberry Pi Zero at regular time intervals, independent from the main thread:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.refresh = None

    def useful_method(self, param):
        print(param)

    def refresh_token(self):
        print('%s Refreshing the token' % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

    def set_token_refresh(self, period_seconds = None):
        # Establish regular token refresh
        if self.refresh:
            self.refresh.cancel()
            self.refresh = None
        if period_seconds:
            def refresh():
                self.refresh_token()
                self.refresh = Timer(period_seconds, refresh) 
                self.refresh.start()
            self.refresh = Timer(period_seconds, refresh) 
            self.refresh.start()

s = Session()
s.set_token_refresh(3) # Every 3 seconds

# Do other things with the Session object
```

This lets me to leave the session object alone and let the token updates be carried out in background, or I can use it for other things, knowing that the token refreshing is being taken care of.

For practical demo, in this example code the period is 3 seconds. In the production code it is 180 seconds. The problem is, this code runs mostly fine, but then one call to `refresh_token()` happens way later than 180 seconds (in the instances I am investigating, 1100 or 1828 seconds later). And then the consequential calls once again are after correct time period. Unfortunately, if the token is refreshed too late, the session is no more valid. This happens when the code is idle, and there does not seem to be anything special about the time when this happens — date/time is not changed or anything.

It's not clear how to debug this, as the problem could not be provoked. Are there any known issues with using `threading.Timer` reliably?

Comment: If you want to schedule then you can use CRONTAB

Comment: @LalitVerma crontab is not an option, as I need to use the same session object within this python program.

Comment: Do your refreshes have a timeout?

Comment: @fafl how do you mean it? In the production code, the new token is received from a sockets server. At the server side, the token is prepared and returned without hesitation. There is no evidence in logs that the socket would be disconnected.

Comment: Do your logs show how long the `refresh_token` method is running? Can it run for 1100 seconds?

Comment: @fafl I will add this to logging, and see if that's the case.